# Export a function outside the form in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react js in my application, antd library. Especially i use this component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wsuv8

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space key={field.key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="start">
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, 'first']}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'first']}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing first name' }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, 'last']}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'last']}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing last name' }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

I want to write this:

```js
 <Form.Item>
             <Button
              type="dashed"
              onClick={() => {
             add();
            }}
              block
           >
            <PlusOutlined /> Add field
         </Button>
     </Form.Item>
```

outside the `<Form>` component, and to put it bellow it. I tried to copy the `add` function from     `{(fields, { add, remove }) => {` and to write it outside the form, but there is a loop and i could not to do that.

 Question: How to achieve what i described above?